# Greedy Algorithm approach to a modified Nearby School/Postoffice example

Tags: algorithm, greedy

I have been trying to solve a practice problem from my professors note but could not find a optimal solution.The following is the problem.

Along a west-east street there are m public schools that respectively have distances, S[1] < S[2] < … < S[m], to the west end of the street. In addition to the m schools, there are n houses which have distances H[1] < H[2] < … < H[n] to the west end of the street, respectively. Currently, a student from any house can find a school that is within 200 meter walking distance. Now, because the budget is short, we wish to close some schools. Please design an O(n+m) greedy algorithm to select a minimum number of schools to be open such that any home still can find one of these selected schools that is within 200 meter walking distance. You need to show a pseudo code and prove the correctness of your algorithm.

Comment: The ordering of the two distance arrays suggests a _dynamic programming_ approach.

Comment: Please tell me if you need a runnable code snippet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**High Level Thoughts**

First, we know solution always exist, by not removing any schools.

For choosing minimum schools, let's think in another way:

> For each house at h[i], think as a range `[h[i]-200, h[i]+200]` inclusively

So, for every such range, we want to find some school  at `s[j]` where  `h[i]-200 <= s[j] <= h[i]+200`

As both `h[]` & `s[]` is sorted, let's see from the leftmost house `[h[0]-200, h[0]+200]`, we **MUST** choose one school for this house, intuitively, we want to choose the **rightmost** school possible, as this school has a **higher chance** to **share with next house**

This idea is true in general case:

> For range h[i], we always want to choose school which is **already chosen school by h[i-?], or the rightmost non chosen school**

**Correctness**

Let a solution is an ordered set of schools `S`, which is not found by the method described

Let the solution found by our greedy method be an ordered set of schools `G`

Conside `S[0]` and `G[0]`, `S[0] <= G[0]` as we choose the rightmost possible school for the first house. Then either

1. `S[0] <= G[0] <= S[1]`, we can replace `S[0]` by `G[0]` which provides same set size
2. `S[0] < S[1] < ... < S[X] <= G[0] <= S[X+1]`, we can replace all `S[X]` <= `G[0]`by `G[0]`, which provides a smaller / more optimal size

*(Yes indeed case 1 is a sub-case of case 2)*

For both cases, remove `G[0]` and any `S[X] <= G[0]`, the scenario is the same with two reduced set, we can use similar arguments, recursively, to say that **our greedy method would not do worse than any possible solutions, which is optimal**

**Pseudo Code**

```js
Pointer house_pointer = first house, school_pointer = first school;

for( each house ){
   if( NOT ( current school is chosen and within current house's range ) ){
       while(current school is NOT the rightmost school within range){
            school_pointer = current school = next school
       }
       mark current school chosen
   }
   house_pointer = next house
}
```

It seems like there is two loops in the algorithm, which is `O(nm)`, but it is not true.  For these type of structure (for eg `KMP algorithm`) which uses two-pointers to iterate through an array, very often you can observe the **maximum** # of times each elements would be accessed.

For the houses, as each iteration would move to next house, each house is at most be accessed 1 time.

For the schools, as the pointer only move forward but not backward, each school is at most accessed 1 time as well, though not evenly distributed for each house iteration (depends on implementation, some schools maybe accessed 2 times but that's not important)

Therefore, combine both, the complexity is still `O(n+m)`

Answer (score 0):

From the initial state in the question we know |S[1] - H[j]| <= 200, for some j, so we can start from there.

We choose to drop the first school if |S[2] - H[j]| <= 200, and we will drop the second school if |S[3] - H[j]| <= 200 ... so on an so forth. The idea is to be greedy and maximize the coverage on a school such that it is at maximal distance from the next house that needs to be covered.

In general, for a school at S[i] and a house at H[j], we will drop the school if |S[i+1] - H[j]| <= 200. If |S[i+1] - H[j]| > 200 then we keep the school at S[i] and find the next house not within distance of S[i]. The algorithm completes once all the houses have been covered. The runtime is O(n+m) since in the worst case we iterate through S and H once.

To prove the correctness you should try considering an optimal sequence and proving that your greedy solution will not do worse. Eg. Given an optimal solution of schools O[1] < O[2] < ... < O[K] and your greedy solution of G[1] < G[2] < ... < G[L], prove that L <= K.